# Inbuilt apache on OSX Mavericks | file location

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

Once I have started the server via Terminal, where is the default location for my index.html file to be saved to?
Or is there no default, and i have to explicitly call out where I want to put it? and if so, how do i do that?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The default directory is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`

You know that there is already one set up because when you go to `http://localhost`, you see this (via [here](http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/))

[image]

You can also put your documents in `/Users/[USER]/Sites` and access it via `localhost/~[USER]`.

To change the directory (via the above link):

- Open `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:
- On line 170, change the `DocumentRoot` to whatever your desired directory is (eg. `DocumentRoot “/www”`)
- On line 197, change the `Directory` location (eg. `<Directory “/www”>`)
- On line 217 (within the `Directory` location we just updated), change the AllowOverride to “All” so that we can use .htaccess to modify any settings for our local sites (ie. `AllowOverride All`)
- On line 429, uncomment the `Include` of the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file (ie. `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`)

Comment: Thanks...2 points.
1 - i dont have access to edit the index.html file in /Library/WebServer/Documents, so i cant put my own in there and overwrite it.
2 - i see the index.html file in /Users/[USER]/Sites, but what do i add to the URL in Safari to navigate to it? you said localhost/~[USER] , i tried http://localhost/[USER] (no brackets) but no joy.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: @DSHEP Did you look at the link I said? It answers all your questions. For your 2nd question, you didn't enter the `~` after the `/`.

Comment: I did but it left some questions unanswered as im not very familiar with Terminal. I did however get it working. I went to Library/WebServers/Documents, and created myself a folder in there. If i go to localhost/MyFolder then it brings up my index.html, css file and any other images etc :)

Comment: @DSHEP Great! Please +1 and tick if you found my answer helpful :). So did it work with the `~`?

Comment: I didn't try it as I have now already set up my subfolder and configured my tools to point to there as my local root

Comment: @DSHEP Ah... OK. But if you want to try it again - then remember to put the `~` :).